# Вместо русских букв тире (-)

Tags: php, mysql

на сайте создаю новость
после перехода в полную версию новости, в url вместо русских букв - тире
причем тире стоит на месте пробелов
в чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1):

например в

```
preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z\/:]/','-','url');
```

Опишите чем пользуетесь, куда загружаете итп.
Тогда будет более полный ответ.